# better way to do this list comprehension python

Tags: python, list, aggregate, list-comprehension

I have many python lists like this A,B,C,...

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
B = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

The output I want is

```
C = [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c'], [4, 'd'], [5, 'e']]
```

The best thing that comes to my mind is

```
C = [[i,k] for i,k in zip(A,B)]
```

But I have many lists to aggerate, what is the other better solution?

Comment: `[list(pair) for pair in zip(A, B, C, D, etc)]`

Comment: How many lists are we talking about? Because what you wrote is a perfectly sensible way to get the output you want.

Comment: There are about 8 lists, and it makes the code look bit less readable @Jasmijn

Comment: If the inner lists could be tuples it's a simple `list(zip(A, B))`. Otherwise the solution presented by @AbdulNiyasPM is fine (or you could write it in functional style as `list(map(list, zip(A, B)))`).

Answer (score 0):

Zip works for as many lists as you want.

```
>>> zip([1, 2, 3], "abc", [True, False, None])
[(1, 'a', True), (2, 'b', False), (3, 'c', None)]
```